# Access other modules to obtain information in them in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

In the AODV network, I set the application layer app of a certain node to udpEchoApp, and I hope to make some modifications in the cc file so that the routing table information of the node can be obtained in the application layer app. How should I do it, I have tried to use the following method
`cModule *parent=getParentModule(); cModule * sub=parent->getSubModule(routingTableRecorder);`

But I still don't know how to use it, and the second sentence of code error is displayed. Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the application one can use `findModuleByPath()` to get the routing table of own node, for example that way:

```
#include "inet/networklayer/ipv4/Ipv4RoutingTable.h"

cModule *mod = findModuleByPath("^.ipv4.routingTable"); // ^ means parent module
if (mod) {
    IIpv4RoutingTable *rt = dynamic_cast<IIpv4RoutingTable*>(mod);
      if (rt) {
         // now a routing table can be printed
         for (int i = 0; i < rt->getNumRoutes(); i++) {
             Ipv4Route *e = rt->getRoute(i);
             EV << e << endl;
         }
     }
}
```